# Why does the navbar-custom styles not apply bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

Ok so I am trying to customize a basic bootstrap navbar using a custom css file, which is included in the html file after the bootstrap cdn. Other styles applied there work just fine, but I can't figure out why the navbar background-color is not changing. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```css
.navbar-custom{
  background-color: #0e3572;
}
.jumbotron{
  background-color: #15438e;
  text-align: center;
}
.jumbotron p{
  color:white;
  font-family: "Bookman Old Style";
}
.jumbotron h2{
  color:white;
  font-family: "Bookman Old Style";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta lang="en">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>PixelCoward Studios</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- JQuery UI -->
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
            integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>

        <nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role = "navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class = "navbar-header">
                    <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle"
                            data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#example-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">PixelCoward Studios</a>
                </div>

                <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example-navbar-collapse">

                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class = "active"><a href = "#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Our Work</a></li>

                        <li class = "dropdown">
                            <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown">
                                Contact
                                <b class = "caret"></b>
                            </a>

                            <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href = "#">Team</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Credits</a></li>
                                <li class = "divider"></li>
                                <li><a href = "#">Email Us</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section>
         <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Hello there!</h2>
            <p>We are an IT company specialized in developing mobile apps and websites</p>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which styles are not applying? The order you list them and rules of precedence is important here.

Comment: The background color is changing ok: http://www.codeply.com/go/q7r8svZbHs

Comment: @ZimSystem It is also changing in my browser but not working in stack overflow code snippet..just curious..Can you suggest an explanation for that?

Comment: well that's curios...in my browser(chrome) the background of the navbar remains as default, but in the link @ZimSystem provided the navbar-custom style is applying

Comment: It's almost certainly because of the ordering. You need to specify your styles *after* the Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: @DavidG but I have used the same order as I have used in my browser but still not working in SO snippet..strange enough!

Answer (score 0):

Add all of your custom css to a page and name it **custom.css**
Now under the Bootstrap css line in the header add a new line like this

```
**<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Custom CSS: You can use this stylesheet to override any Bootstrap styles and/or apply your own styles -->
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">**
```